# Dynamically create robot keywords in Python

Tags: python, robotframework

I have a python library that implements robot framework keywords.
I'm trying to generate a test suite automatically given a yaml file, but can't get one of the steps to work.

This is the simplified code:

```
from robot.api import TestSuite
from robot.api.deco import keyword
import yaml

@keyword("Request Api Call")
def request_api_call(request_type, api_url, query_params, headers, body, expected_status):
    # Does the API call

@keyword("Generate Robot Tests")
def generate_robot_tests(test_cases, file_path):
    suite = TestSuite(suite_name)
    for test_case in test_cases:
        test = suite.tests.create(test_case_name)
        test.body.create_keyword('Request Api Call', args=[request_type_value, api_url_value, query_params_value, headers_value, body_value, expected_status_value])
    return suite
```

The problem is in `test.body.create_keyword`. It doesn't recognize the `Request Api Call` keyword.

When I call that keyword directly from the .robot file which imports this python file, it works.
I'm guessing it's some sort of scope problem, but not sure how to solve it.

What I'm trying to accomplish is to run each test individually (to get the separate logs and test results), so I thought I could create a Test Suite per yaml file and then a Test Case per entry in that yaml file.

Any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You've created a Robot Framework test suite using the robot.api module and added a test with a custom setup step. Typically, if you're executing a keyword that already exists, you won't face this issue. If you want to create your own custom keywords or use keywords from a different library, you need to ensure that the corresponding library is imported into your suite.

Import a custom library:

```
suite.resource.imports.library('path.to.your.CustomLibrary')
```